# Import existing Azure resources

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I published a bot from bot framework composer successfully by selecting "Import existing resources".
but I can not find my bot on azure portal.How can I find my bot?

Comment: Head to https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ProjectOxford/AppliedAIHub/BotServices, ensure you're logged in under an account with access to view your resource, remove any filters to ensure you're seeing everything.

Comment: Thank you .and sorry for late response. I don not find it on the page of bot service. because my existing resource is a qna maker resource. I modified the publish configuration and publish successfully.